# Build URL without configuring urlManager in /config/main.php

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

I want to be able to map definite string values such 'index.html' on URLs such mydomain/index.php?r=page/view&id=1. 
Id/value pairs should be stored in the database, therefore hardcoding urlManager rules in the /config/main.php is unsuitable for my purposes. 
I'm using yii-1.1.16.

Comment: I think **Faking url suffix** can solve your problem. Please refer [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#faking-url-suffix) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change url-manager to this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'urlSuffix'=>'.html',
    'caseSensitive'=>false
    'rules'=>array(
        'pattern1'=>array('<controller:page>/<action:view>/<id:\d+>', 
    ),  

),
```

This can be helpful.

**Update:**

If you want to map `/index.php/page/view/id/1` url to `mydomain/about.html`, you need to do following works:

**1.Remove `index.php` from url:** For removing `index.php`, you can easily refer to [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x). Then you need to enable apache RewriteModule in `httpd.conf`.

**2.Add a rule in url-manager:** I updated the url-manager rule and now this is look like this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
     'urlFormat'=>'path',
     'showScriptName' => false,
     'urlSuffix'=>'.html',
     'caseSensitive'=>false
     'rules'=>array(
         'about'=>'page/view/id/1',
         'pattern1'=>array('<controller:page>/<action:view>/<id:\d+>',
),
```

),

Note that, no need to repeat `index.php` in all url-manager rules.
Good luck!

Comment: @ETartaren Did you try that?

Comment: Yes I tried now. I write it project after hours,  therefore could not answer during the day.  This is helpful. My URL now look like '/index.php/page/view/id/2.html'.

Comment: This mode of display URL will be in my system, as well as simple 'path' mode. But I will be completely happy if I will be able doing URLs such like 'mydomain/about.html' and to associate with 'path' URLs such like /index.php/page/view/id/1'.

Comment: I will update my answer for your second requirement.

Comment: Thank you. I have successfully removed index.php from url, but rule 'about'=>'page/view/id/1' not take effect. Url as before looks like '/page/view/id/2.html'.

Comment: You are welcome! Did you try "yourdomain/about.html" as your url? This will be mapped to "page/view/id/1".

Comment: Oh, excuse me! "mydomain/about.html" is realy mapped to "page/view/id/1". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Now I trying to use faking url suffix.

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            'pattern1'=>array('<controller:page>/<action:view>/<id:\d+>', 
            'urlSuffix'=>'.html', 'caseSensitive'=>false)
        ),
    ),
```

When I enter URL '/index.php/page/view/id/1' it remains the same. 'mydomain/index.php/page/view/id/2' instead 'mydomain/1.html'